# Does anyone know the full form of S/ KEY?

Tags: authentication, cryptography

Out of curiosity, I just want to know the full form of "S/KEY" authentication method.
What does 'S' stand for ? and why is it written like S/KEY ?

Comment: What protocol is this about?

Answer (score 2):

According to [RFC1760](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1760) and the [original paper](http://zoo.cs.yale.edu/classes/cs422/2014/bib/haller94skey.pdf), it would stand for "secret key". More specifically, `S` would stand for the initial secret used in the hash chain.

> A sequence of one-time passwords is produced by applying the secure
> hash function multiple times to the output of the preparatory step
> (**called S**).  That is, the first one-time password is produced by
> passing S through the secure hash function a number of times (N)
> specified by the user. The next one-time password is generated by
> passing S though the secure hash function N-1 times.

Answer (score 0):

I've always heard/been told that S/KEY just means Secure Key or Security Key. As for why it's written that way, I have no idea, but I would assume it's just short-hand to not have to type the whole thing.